# In which table Pimcore stores Emails log?

Tags: one-time-password, pimcore

Pimcore sends emails and keeps the copy on the server.

Where are they located?

And how safe they are?

Do they need some additional protection?

My local server is configured not to send emails -- just ignores.

If I have SQL-dump of Pimcore website but don't know admin password, how can I read the one-time password generated by devhost for password resetting-reminding?

Answer (score 0):

ID, Subject and email addresses you can see in MySQL/MariaDB table:

```
SELECT * FROM `email_log` ORDER BY `email_log`.`sentDate` DESC
```

HTML/text content body find in the file using ID from table:

```
PIMCORE_LOG_MAIL_PERMANENT . '/email-' . $this->getId() . '-html.log'
```

e.g.:

- /var/email/email-1234-html.log
- /var/email/email-1234-text.log